# Work with Json files in Django (Static files)

Tags: json, django

I want to work with `json` files in my project but it crashes.

I read that my `json` file has to be inside the static folder. Thus I create inside this folder a new one called "data" and I put the file inside.

Furthermore I saw that some people has to add inside the `settings.py` the following code line and I did it too.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS =[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

I don't know what can I do more, I don't know if the file is in a wrong path or if I have to do something more.

The error is the following:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/arxiu.json'

Can someone help me please?

**Code (views.py):**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd
import json

def coordenadas(request):
    lat = 9.1234567
    lon = 12.1234567
    code = obtener_datos()
    ctx = {'Lat':lat,'Lon':lon, 'code':code}

    return render(request,'map.html', ctx)


def obtener_datos():
    code = 0

    with open('data/arxiu.json') as file:
        file = json.load(file)

    return code
```

*When I delete the two json lines the program works, accordingly the problem is here.*

Answer (score 2):

I think you have problem with path, which should be relative to `BASE_DIR` variable. Please try this solution:

```
from django.conf import settings
import os
...
def obtener_datos():
  code = 0

  with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static/data/arxiu.json')) as file:
    file = json.load(file)

  return code
```

Comment: Is not working, before the error was finding the path, now is a `Internar server error`

Comment: What does the error says?

Comment: `This site can’t be reached` `127.0.0.1 refused to connect.`

Comment: And what does django `runserver` console says as an error

Comment: `NameError: name 'settings' is not define` but `settings.py` is in the correct place and contains `BASE_DIR`

Comment: you should import settings using `from django.conf import settings` (as shown in answer)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you with your problem. [Good Explanation Link.](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/)

You need to set up your files like this:

```
# or, eg,
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Comment: I added in `settings.py` but it crashes, the error is `Internal server error`